# How to copy the contents of all files with a certain name into a new file?

Tags: linux

What I want to do is search for all the files whose name meet a certain requirement (starts with 's', followed by either a '1' or a '2' and end with 'sh') and then copy the contents of all those files into a new file, (name ending with `.txt`).

So far, what I think it should look like is this:

```
cat / "s[1-2]*sh" >> /home/admin/Desktop/myFile.txt
```

But it does not work, reporting

```
cat: /: Is a directory
```

I'm completely out of ideas. I'm running ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: All files everywhere or all files in a certain directory?

Comment: All files everywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To concatenate the files in your current directory:

```
cat s[12]*sh > /home/admin/Desktop/myFile.txt
```

To find and concatenate the files in your current directory and subdirectories:

```
find . -name "s[12]*sh" -exec cat '{}' > /home/admin/Desktop/myFile.txt \;
```

To find and concatenate the files everywhere:

```
find / -name "s[12]*sh" -exec cat '{}' > /home/admin/Desktop/myFile.txt \;
```

Comment: note that `find -exec cat {} > out.txt \;` is exactly equivalent to `find -exec cat {}  \; > out.txt` as the shell processes the redirection before `find` runs, and it applies to the whole `find` process. So you might as well put the `\;` before the redirection for clarity. Also, you can use `-exec cat {} +` to have `find` pass more than one file name to each `cat` invocation. The effect is the same, but it can be faster for large numbers of files.

Comment: To accept an answer click the ✓

Comment: `-exec cat {} +` would be more efficient as it would call `cat` as few times as possible.